# How to get the wlan number in the linux system using BASH script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a script to enable the wireless driver.

If I input `iwconfig` in the terminal, it will give me the following output:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan3     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

What I want to do next is to input:

`ifconfig wlan3 up`

Is there a way to extract the number `3` from the first output and make those into a bash script?

Comment: why do you need the 3 alone if all you need is `wlan3`?

Comment: If you want your script run on all linux systems, then you can not even use the `wlan` prefix. A few days ago when I install Gentoo, the wlan interface is named `wlp2s0`.

Answer (score 3):

`iwconfig` prints *only* wireless interfaces to `stdout`, other output is in fact `stderr`. Therefore the following command will work regardless of interface name.

```
$ iwconfig 2>/dev/null | grep -o "^\w*"
```

Answer (score 2):

if you just want want `ifconfig wlan3 up`, then you don't need to isolate the 3.

you can get wlan3 with just

```
$ iwconfig | grep -o "^wlan[0-9]\+"
wlan3
```